# How can I dynamically construct a menu with ansible.builtin.pause module?

Tags: ansible, menu, module

The goal here is to dynamically construct a menu from an available variable file

In this example I use `ansible.builtin.pause` module but I'm not sure this is the best way

**variable file: `vars.yml`**

```yaml
---
menu:
  ansible:
    main:
    - option: 1
      name: "Add..."
    - option: 2
      name: "Delete..."
    - option: 3
      name: "Empty..."
    add:
      - option: 1
        name: "Add something..."
      - option: 2
        name: "Add something to..."
    delete:
    empty:
  ssh:
    main:
```

**playbook: `test.yml`**

```yaml
- name: "PLAY: > TEST"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files: vars.yml
  pre_tasks:

  - name: Dynamicaly construct menu
    pause:
      prompt:
        "\n
        Ansible options:\n
        =====================================\n
        {{item.option}}- {{item.name}}"
    register: result
    loop: "{{menu.ansible.main}}"

  - debug: 
      msg: "Option 1 was selected"
    when: result.user_input == '1'
```

**Output:**

```
PLAY [PLAY: > TEST] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Dynamicaly construct menu] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[Dynamicaly construct menu]

 Ansible options:
 =====================================
 1- Add...:
```

As you can see it displays only part of the main, not all.

**Question:**

How can I display all available options at once and save user selection, so I can run next tasks based on conditions?

I'm pretty sure the menu must be first generated and saved under one variable before sending to `ansible.builtin.pause` but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where including loops directly in the inlined jinja2 template will be hardly avoidable (and is therefore acceptable):

```yaml
  - name: Dynamicaly construct menu
    pause:
      prompt: |-
        Ansible options:
        =====================================
        {% for option in menu.ansible.main %}
        {{ option.option }}- {{ option.name }}
        {% endfor %}
    register: result
```

Result with that fixed task:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [PLAY: > TEST] ***************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Dynamicaly construct menu] **************************************************************************************************
[Dynamicaly construct menu]
Ansible options:
=====================================
1- Add...
2- Delete...
3- Empty...
:
1^Mok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Option 1 was selected"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [PLAY: > TEST] ***************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Dynamicaly construct menu] **************************************************************************************************
[Dynamicaly construct menu]
Ansible options:
=====================================
1- Add...
2- Delete...
3- Empty...
:
2^Mok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Zeitounator that works perfectly fine thanks for your help!